# mock botocore.vendored requests with requests_mock and pytest

Tags: python, python-requests, boto3

I am trying to mock a get request with `requests_mock`, but it doesn't seem to get it right.

My function calling a third-party API defined in a file `lookup.py`:

```
from botocore.vendored import requests

def get_data():
   url = 'https://abc.something.com/datapackage'
   url_params={
      'v': 2,
      'auth_apikey':'xyz'
   }
   resp = requests.get(url, params=url_params)
   return resp.json()
```

I am using `py.test` to run my tests and in my test file. I have a fixture:

```
  import requests_mock
  import requests, pytest
  from lookup import get_data

  @pytest.fixture
  def req_mock(request):
    m = requests_mock.Mocker()
    m.start()
    request.addfinalizer(m.stop)
    return m

  def test_api_gets_data(req_mock):
      sample={
          'key1':123
      }
      lookup_url = 'https://abc.something.com/datapackage'
      query_params = {
        'v': 2,
        'auth_apikey':'xyz'
      }
      req_mock.get(lookup_url, json=sample)
      resp = get_data()
```

Apparently, `requests_mock` isn't able to use the same session as the requests in the `get` function, so it isn't getting mocked.

Is there a better way to do this?

I'm using Python 3.6, requests 2.18, requests-mock 1.52 and pytest 3.0.7.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/alevikpes/dev-utils/blob/master/python3_unittest_mock_requests.py) was working for me

Comment: Sorry I just realised while creating this post I used the wrong import. I am trying to use requests from botocore, which is AWS package and core of boto3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't mock `from botocore.vendored import requests` with `requests_mock`.

Instead use `unittest.mock` to mock the response.

```
  from unittest import mock

  class MockResponse:
    def __init__(self, status_code, json_data=None):
      self.json_data = json_data
      self.status_code = status_code

   def json(self):
      return self.json_data

   def raise_for_status(self):
      if self.status_code >= 500:
        raise Exception

 item_not_found = {
    "Response": {
      "StatusCode": "ItemNotFound",
    }
 }

 item_not_found_resp = MockResponse(200, item_not_found)


 @mock.patch('botocore.vendored.requests.get', return_value=item_not_found_resp)
 def test_api_returns_not_found_when_third_party_api_returns_item_not_found(mc):
     resp = get(e1, c)
     exp_resp = {
       "statusCode": 404,
       "body": json.dumps({
        'error': 'no item found'
       })
     }
   request_url = mc.call_args[0][0]
   request_params = mc.call_args[1]['params']
   assert lookup_url == request_url
   assert query_params == request_params
   assert exp_resp == resp
```

Answer (score 0):

at `lookup.py` files, `lookup_url` will `raise NameError` cause name `lookup_url` not defined.

use `url` and don't forget to change `params=url_params`, so the code will be something like this:

`resp = requests.get(url, params=url_params)`

Comment: thanks for the correction. I hadnt properly edited the code.